# <Route path="" component = {}/> doesn't show the component in react

Tags: reactjs, routes

I use Router component in my react app to show different components when clicking the navbar. however, when I click a link in navbar, the address shows the path but the component which I call when the path equals that, is now shown in the page. 

this is my App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./Components/navBar";
import Header from "./Components/ddrHeader";
import Home from "./Components/home";
import Plan from "./Components/plan";
import Waiting from "./Components/waiting";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} />
            <Route path="/ddr" Component={Header} />
            <Route path="/plan" Component={Plan} />
            <Route path="/waiting" Component={Waiting} />
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is my index.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
// import DDR from './Components/ddr';
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.register();
```

and this is my navbar :

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <Link className="nav-link" to="/">
                Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <Link className="nav-link" to="/ddr">
                DDR
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <Link className="nav-link" to="/plan">
                Plan
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <Link className="nav-link" to="/waiting">
                Waiting
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: any reason you use `Router` again inside `Navbar`. it is already inside the router from app.js!

Comment: @Panther , just a mistake . I omitted the one in navbar. but the problem exists.

Comment: Can you set up your project with codesandbox.io ?

Comment: @jdn , here's a quick sample  : https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-router-sample-3prg3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [react-router(component prop)](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component). The prop **Component** is wrong, should be **component**

```
<Switch>
   // <Route exact path="/" Component={Home} /> // wrong
   <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> //correct
</Switch>
```